# How to tell PHP static code analysers to read the generic type hint from a callable, instead of expecting the class name as a string?

Tags: php, static-analysis, phpstan, psalm-php

I'm trying to remove some code duplication that has proven to be prone to human errors.

I created a working sample code at https://3v4l.org/QFA6m#v8.2.7 and a demo of PHPStan failing where expected, https://phpstan.org/r/e6310a8c-6691-4096-a698-44eadb1ab1f2

On a high level:

1. I am using DTO capable of creating an object of another class

   1. `interface CrudDto` defines `public function apply(): CrudEntity`
   2. `class CreatePersonDto implements CrudDto` and its `apply()` method returns a `Person`
   3. `class Person extends CrudEntity`
2. There is a `CrudManager` class capable of working with my DTO through `CrudManager::save(CrudDto $dto): CrudEntity`
3. Calling `$crudManager->save($dto)` returns whatever the given DTO can create: `PersonCreateDto` -> `Person`, `CatCreateDto` -> `Cat` and so on, you get the point.

**I'm trying to tell CrudManager that it's not returning a `CrudEntity`, but a `Person`, or a `Cat`, etc.**

I achieved so by passing the expected class name to my save function and using things described here https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-by-examples#accept-a-class-string-and-return-the-object-of-that-type

But here comes the core of the question (thanks for reading until this point, btw!)

I would love to insulate the strict type checking so that the developer doesn't have to provide the expected type to the `save()` method via a `class-string<T of CrudEntity> $className`.

I want to do that because if the DTO knows what class it is creating, it should be able to give that information to whoever wants it.

I added `CrudDto::belongsTo(): string` that returns the FQCN of whatever the entity the DTO can produce, and I can use that value to enforce the actual type on runtime, but I didn't find a way to inform static code analysers that the class-string is provided by the DTO itself, not by the argument next to it.

Effectively I'm looking for a pseudocode of something like this:

```php
/**
 * @template T of CrudEntity
 * @param class-string<T> $dto::belongsTo()
 */
public function save(CrudDto $dto): CrudEntity;
```

**In other words,** I'd like to tell PHPStan, PHPStorm, psalm and others, that if `CreatePersonDto::belongsTo()` returns `Person::class`, calling `$entityManager->save($personDto)` returns `Person`, not just `CrudDto`.

Can it be done without passing the expected return value's class name as a method argument of the `save()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. See https://phpstan.org/r/50d160ac-e66c-4079-a8b6-474d0614cf56

First, you need to make your `CrudDto` interface generic:

```php
/** @template T of CrudEntity */
interface CrudDto {
  // ...
}
```

Then, for every DTO implementation specify `/** @extends CrudDto<EntityClass> */`:

```php
/** @implements CrudDto<Person> */
abstract class PersonDto implements CrudDto {
  // ...
}
```

And then you can make the `CrudManager::save()` method generic:

```php
    /**
     * @template T of CrudEntity
     * @param CrudDto<T> $dto
     * @return T
     */
    public function save(CrudDto $dto): CrudEntity {
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: That does solve part of the problem (it allows CrudManager to indicate the correct entity) but it relies on the correct template annotation on each DTO. 

I am curious if the value of `T` in `CrudDto<T>` can be extracted from a method call on the `$dto` parameter. Here is why: in the real code I am using the value provided by `CrudDto::belongsTo()` for a few things, so I was hoping to be able to use its return value to tell phpstan what the T is. In other words, I was trying to avoid having to synchronise the return value of `belongsTo()` with the `@implements` comment.

Comment: No, that's not possible with either Psalm or PHPStan. The reasons for that would be too hard to explain in a comment, but you're welcome to bring the idea to either tool's issue tracker. As one of the Psalm maintainers, I'm pretty sure the result will be "ain't gonna happen" though.

Comment: On the upside though, either tool will make sure the `@implements` annotations and the `belongsTo()` implementations are present, correct and do not contradict each other, as long as your DTOs are checked by the SA tool.

Comment: I guess I could use `@return class-string<T>` on my `belongsTo()` interface. Thank you. Confirming something isn't possible is as important as being told what I am missing!